# How do I remove zeroes from a positive array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code:

```
package javaapplication11;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class JavaApplication11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array [] = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
        System.out.println(array.length);

        int negative[];
        int positive[];

        int counter = 0;
        int counter2 = 1; 

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            if(array[i]<0){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        negative = new int[counter];
        positive = new int[array.length-counter];

        for(int i=0,n=0,p=0;i<array.length;i++){
            if(array[i]<0){
                negative[n++]=array[i];
            } else  {
                positive[p++]=array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negative)); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(positive));

        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        for(int i=1;i<array.length-1;i++){
            if(array[i] == array[i-1]){
                System.out.println("Duplicate: " +array[i]);
            }    
        }
    }   
}
```

My output looks like this:

- 13
- [12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87]
- [-22, -4, -55, -999, -87]
- [12, 23, 0, 43, 545, 43, 12, 0]
- [-999, -87, -55, -22, -4, 0, 0, 12, 12, 23, 43, 43, 545]
- Duplicate: 0
- Duplicate: 12
- Duplicate: 43

I need to remove zeros from positive array. How?

Comment: Are you forced to use Array? Could you use a List ?

Comment: please note, you can't resize your array.

Comment: Don't use an array. They have immutable length once created. If you want to remove something, what you have to do is create a new array with the `ogArray.length - 1` and then copy everything but the thing you want to exclude into that new array.

Comment: I am forced to use array that is a problem with List is easier.

Answer (score 1):

The zeros can be ignored while manipulating the positive numbers:

```
for(int i=0, n=0, p=0;i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 0) {
       negative[n++] = array[i];
    } else if (array[i] > 0) {
         positive[p++] = array[i];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No it still have zeros in array. Thanks anyway :D